# How to block a specific youtube video on ubuntu?

Tags: network-manager, youtube, hosts

I can already block whole websites using /etc/hosts. Right now I want to block some specific Youtube videos for all users. The exact URL blocking is not working and the URL itself is dynamic. How can I block it?

Comment: Check these browser addons if one of them suits you: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/search/?q=block%20websites

Comment: That will not prevent someone to do a wget from command line :)  I would suggest using socal methods.